# How to access snapshot of Firebase database within Firebase Function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Every hour, I want my firebase function to look through my database, read a value, calculate a new value from this old value, and then update it in the database. I am having trouble accessing a snapshot of the data. Specificically,

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 hour').onRun((context) => {
  const ref = functions.database.ref('/users/test_user/commutes');
  ref.once('value',function(snapshot) {
   // do new calculation here

  }, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
  });
  return null;
});
```

I am getting a : `functions: TypeError: ref.once is not a function` error.

How do I access a value from my firebase real time database and update it from a Firebase function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the firebase-functions SDK to query the database.  It can't do that.  You will have to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to make the query.

You will need to get started like this (not complete, but you should be able to see what you need to do).  Import and initialize at the global scope:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()
```

Then in your function, use it.  Be sure to work with promises correctly.

```
const ref = admin.database().ref('...')
return ref.once('value').then(snapshot => {
    // work with the snapshot here, and return another promise
    // that resolves after all your updates are complete
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `firebase-functions` is different from the client side. The `ref()` function according to the docs:

> ref: function
>
> `ref(path: string): RefBuilder`
>
> Select Firebase Realtime Database Reference to listen to.
>
> Path of the database to listen to.
>
> Returns RefBuilder

The `RefBuilder` will contain the database triggers that you can call, `onCreate()`, `onWrite()`. To be able to use your database, then you need to use the admin sdk.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder